# oauth2-server-php creates new token every time

Tags: php

I'm using this one to check the email and password, if they're correct, it will return an access token:

`curl -u u:p http://localhost/api/token -d 'grant_type=password&username=example@example.com&password=123456'`

But every time I request, it creates new token.

Can oauth2-server-php check, if the token existed, just return ?

Thank you very much for reading, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Set a expiry of the token.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
The problem is: if user logout => login, then logout => login, logout => login.... too much tokens will be born